# removeClass on sibling div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

This is the structure of the HTML :

```
<div class="agShowBox">
     <div class="agEmpty"> </div>
     <div class="agShowImgBox">
           <div class="centerImg">
           <div class="centerImg">
           <div class="centerImg">
           <div class="centerImg">
           <div class="centerImg">
           <div class="centerImg hideThis">
           <div class="clearit"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="agRightArrow">
          <img alt="next" src="images/arrow_right.png">
     </div>
     <div class="clearit"></div>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
$("#agMidBox").on('click', '.agRightArrow', function() {
    $(this).siblings(".agShowImgBox").children(".centerImg:lt(6)").addClass("hideThis");
    $(this).siblings(".agShowImgBox").children(".centerImg:gt(5)").removeClass("hideThis");                 
});
```

The problem is that I am not able to remove the class `hideThis` from the *6th* div inside the class `agShowImgBox`.

This code is supposed to do that, right

```
$(this).siblings(".agShowImgBox")
       .children(".centerImg:gt(5)")
       .removeClass("hideThis");
```

Adding the class is working. But not removing the class.

Comment: Are you just trying to add and remove the class from a specific div or for a few of them?

Comment: on click of that button I have to addclass to first 5 div and at the same time remove a class for the next 5 divs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) is zero-based. `:gt(5)` will match the elements *after* the sixth one but will not match the sixth element itself.

You should write:

```
$(this).siblings(".agShowImgBox")
       .children(".centerImg:gt(4)")
       .removeClass("hideThis");
```

Comment: Thanks dude.. Got it.. But I don't understand why it is like that!! Greater than 5 means sixth should also be considered rite!

Comment: @SandeepRao, well, since the indices are zero-based, *greater than index 5* actually means *after the sixth item* (the first item has index 0). You'll get used to it eventually :)